# Flask SQLAlchemy get columns from two joined mapped entities in query result

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy

I have a table, `MenuOptions` which represents any option found in a dropdown in my app. Each option can be identified by the menu it is part of (e.g. `MenuOptions.menu_name`) and the specific value of that option (`MenuOptions.option_value`).

This table has relationships all across my db and doesn't use foreign keys, so I'm having trouble getting it to mesh with SQLAlchemy.

In SQL it would be as easy as:

```
SELECT 
    *
FROM
    document
        JOIN
    menu_options ON menu_options.option_menu_name = 'document_type'
        AND menu_options.option_value = document.document_type_id
```

to define this relationship. However I'm running into trouble when doing this in SQLAlchemy because I can't map this relationship cleanly without foreign keys. In SQLAlchemy the best I've done so far is:

```
the_doc = db.session.query(Document, MenuOptions).filter(
    Document.id == document_id
).join(
    MenuOptions,
    and_(
        MenuOptions.menu_name == text('"document_type"'),
        MenuOptions.value == Document.type_id
    )
).first()
```

Which does work, and does return the correct values, but returns them as a list of two separate model objects such that I have to reference the mapped Document properties via `the_doc[0]` and the mapped MenuOptions properties via `the_doc[1]`

Is there a way I can get this relationship returned as a single query object with all the properties on it *without using foreign keys or any `ForeignKeyConstraint`* in my model? I've tried `add_columns` and `add_entity` but I get essentially the same result.

Comment: Are you actually asking how to form and eagerload ORM relationships without having a foreign key constraint?

Answer (score 1):

you can use [with_entities](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/orm/query.html#sqlalchemy.orm.query.Query.with_entities)

```
entities = [getattr(Document, c) for c in Document.__table__.columns.keys()] + \
           [getattr(MenuOptions, c) for c in MenuOptions.__table__.columns.keys()]

session.query(Document, MenuOptions).filter(
    Document.id == document_id
).join(
    MenuOptions,
    and_(
        MenuOptions.menu_name == text('"document_type"'),
        MenuOptions.value == Document.type_id
    )
).with_entities(*entities)
```

Comment: hm this has 2 issues, I can't alias the column names in my model and it returns a list and not an object with properties which is too brittle. Definitely a step in the right direction though, thank you

Answer (score 0):

I ended up taking a slightly different approach using `association_proxy`, but if you ended up here from google then this should help you. In the following example, I store a `document_type_id` in the `document` table and hold the corresponding values for that id in a table called `menu_options`. Normally you would use foreign keys for this, but our `menu_options` is essentially an inhouse lookup table, and it contains relationships to several other tables so foreign keys are not a clean solution.

By first establishing a relationship via the `primaryjoin` property, then using `associationproxy`, I can immediately load the `document_type` based on the `document_type_id` with the following code:

```
from sqlalchemy import and_
from sqlalchemy.ext.associationproxy import association_proxy

class Document(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = "document"
    document_type_id = db.Column(db.Integer)
    document_type_proxy = db.relationship(
        "MenuOptions",
        primaryjoin=(
            and_(
                MenuOptions.menu_name=='document_type', 
                foreign('Document.document_type_id')==MenuOptions.value
            )
        ),
        lazy="immediate"
        viewonly=True
    )
```

If all you need is a mapped relationship without the use of foreign keys within your database, then this will do just fine. If, however, you want to be able to access the remote attribute (in this case the `document_type`) directly as an attribute on the initial class (in this case `Document`) then you can use `association_proxy` to do so by simply passing the name of the mapped relationship and the name of the remote property:

```
    document_type = association_proxy("document_type_proxy", "document_type")
```